# Submit form with AJAX to php api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is posting data to a php api file. I got the api working and it creates an account but want to use AJAX to send the data so I can make the UX better. Here is what the PHP sending script is expecting:

```
<form id="modal-signup" action="/crowdhub_api_v2/api_user_create.php" method="post">
                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="user_firstname"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="user_lastname"></input>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="Radio" placeholder="Gender" value="male" name="user_gender">Male</input>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="Radio" placeholder="Gender" value="female"  name="user_gender">Female</input>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="date" placeholder="DOB" name="user_dateofbirth"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-half">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="user_zip"></input>
                </div>

                <input class="end" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="user_email"></input>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="user_password"></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </form>
```

PHP

```
$user_firstname = $_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
    $user_lastname = $_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
    $user_email = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_REQUEST['user_password'];
    $user_zip = $_REQUEST['user_zip'];
    $user_dateofbirth = $_REQUEST['user_dateofbirth'];
    $user_gender = $_REQUEST['user_gender'];
    $user_phone = $_REQUEST['user_phone'];
    $user_newsletter = $_REQUEST['user_newsletter'];
```

How would I send this via ajax? I found this script that says it worked, but it did not create a user. I imagine its sending the data not the right way.

Ajax

```
$(function () {

$('#modal-signup').on('submit', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/api_v2/api_user_create.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  });

});

});
```

Comment: post the html for your form too

Comment: Is that `$_POST`? or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains both POST and GET @aldrin27

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Posted the html. When I just do a regular POST the api on that page says it went threw and a user is made. I would just prefer to send to the PHP with ajax

Comment: you've a few $_REQUEST arrays that aren't in your form, so whether it's relevant or not... - btw, you can safely get rid of all `</input>` it isn't a valid closing tag.

Comment: use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console. Make sure jQuery's loaded too.

Comment: The form works fine as is if I do a regular POST without AJAX so I know the php on the api is fine and the form is fine. I just wanst sure how to do it with AJAX

Comment: You need to answer the questions that @JayBlanchard *(evening Sam)* and I asked. what do you get back?

Comment: one thing I noticed; you're using `action="/crowdhub_api_v2/api_user_create.php"` in the form, yet your ajax shows as `url: '/api_v2/api_user_create.php',` being 2 different paths. Usually, ajax uses on file. I don't know what else to tell you at this point, good luck.

Comment: Without looking at the console you'll never be able to start figuring out the issues. (*Evening Ralph*)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get ajax in order:

```
$(function () {

    $('#modal-signup').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        //same url as the form
        url: '/crowdhub_api_v2/api_user_create.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        //we need a variable here to see what happened with PHP
        success: function (msg) {
          //output to the page
          $('#output').html(msg);
          //or to the console
          //console.log('return from ajax: ', msg);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Somewhere on the form page, add a div with id output:

```
<div id="output></div>
```

Finally, in api_user_create.php, there is an error:

```
$user_gender = $_REQUEST['user_gender'];
//these last two do not exist on the form
$user_phone = $_REQUEST['user_phone'];
$user_newsletter = $_REQUEST['user_newsletter'];
```

I'd recommend some error-checking on the PHP side, like this

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST)){
    //For developing, you may want to just print the incoming data to see what came through
    //This data returns into the msg variable of the ajax function
    print_r($_POST);

    //once that's good, process data
    if(isset($_REQUEST['user_gender'])){
        $user_gender = $_REQUEST['user_gender'];
    }
    //etc... as before
} else {
    echo 'no data received';
}
```

Comment: A user was not created but I got the response from dev tools: `Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80`